# How to get an element from event target closest(name)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm not sure how to use event target `closest([name="..."])` as I understand `closest()` should get the element after I change the value in the input field to calculate, but the elements I get are `null`

```js
function calculate(e) {
    if (e.target.name == 'qty') {
      var elemPrice = e.target.closest('[name="price"]') //***
      var elemAmount = e.target.closest('[name="amount"]') //***
      console.log(elemPrice)
      console.log(elemAmount)
      elemAmount.value = elemPrice.value * e.target.value
    }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    document.getElementsByName('qty').forEach(t => { t.addEventListener('change',calculate) })
})
```

```html
<table>
      <tbody>
                <tr class="uk-hidden">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><input name="price"></td>
                    <td><input name="qty"></td>
                    <td><input name="amount"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="uk-hidden">
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td><input name="price"></td>
                    <td><input name="qty"></td>
                    <td><input name="amount"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="uk-hidden">
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td><input name="price"></td>
                    <td><input name="qty"></td>
                    <td><input name="amount"></td>
                </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried

```
   ...
      var elemPrice = e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.lastElementChild  //***
      var elemAmount = e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.lastElementChild  //***
   ...
```

but I want to do like `closest` Is there a way to do this?

anyways Thank you in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Reading the docs is always a good idea. If we look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest it says:

> The **closest()** method traverses the `Element` and its parents (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the provided selector string. Will return itself or the matching ancestor. If no such element exists, it returns `null`.

So it does not do what you assumed: it *only* checks the path from your element to the document root. What you want is to find the closest `<tr>`, and then find the `name=price` element inside of *that* element:

```
e.target.closest(`tr`).querySelector(`[name=price]`)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I was always looking in the body part. Next time I'll read more focused-ly

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that with TypeScript you must be explicit about the type of element `target` is.

```
highlight($event: Event) {
  let tar = $event?.target as HTMLElement; // HTMLInputElement etc

  console.log(tar);
  // now TS allows access to expected HTMLElement methods like .closest
  console.log(tar.closest('div'));
}
```

It should be noted that passing the entire `event` object is a "dubious practice" according to the Angular docs.

Comment: This wasn't a typescript or angular question, though.?

Comment: True, but this is actually how Angular sends its events. Also, its tricky in TS. Both arent covered in other answers.